# Hololens 2 application development tools

Tags: unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, vuforia, hololens

I am new to AR/VR area and I am trying to build an application in Hololens2. The application is for instructing users how to connect network switches using LAN cables.

Can someone suggest

- Where I can start?
- Which library I can use (I have to track multiple objects)?
- Is is possible to detect cables which I am trying to connect and do augmentation over it?

I tried going through different libraries like vuforia, wikitude (no support found for hololens2), MRTK. but didn't got a clear idea on how I can proceed.

Answer (score 2):

Well, there sure exist a couple of ways to do so, here is my personal suggestion:

1. Use Unity for application development (For me v2021.3.14f/16f works fine in combination with the HL2). To set up Unity for development of an AR application for the HL 2 you will find many resources online, e.g. [Getting Started with unity and HL2 development](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/mixed-reality/develop/unity/unity-development-overview?tabs=arr%2CD365%2Chl2#1-getting-started)
2. As you have come across, MRTK is great for building a UI. They offer many different UI elements out of the box. To install MRTK features, I would also suggest you use the MixedRealityFeatureTool ([MRFeatureTool](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=102778)).
3. For target detection, especially in combination with Unity, I have personally enjoyed working with Vuforia a lot! It can be installed from within Unity and can detect different types of targets ([Vuforia Overview](https://library.vuforia.com/getting-started/vuforia-features)). Maybe you will find something suitable for your use case. My first impression regarding calbes is that they are not well suited for detection. Maybe you can attach markers to the end of your cables and your device or something like that.

Hope that helps as a first entry point. Good luck with your project!